# I am trying to make a discord.js ping command with latency but it shows this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a ping command which shows the latency too but I face a error and I don't know why it is showing it, this is the error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ping')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\commands\utility\ping.js:10:74)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\index.js:78:11)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Ayush Kumar\Desktop\AniVenture\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)      
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Code in ping.js -

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
name: 'ping',  
cooldown: 4,
execute(message, client) {
    const bot = message.createdTimestamp - Date.now();
    const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Pong! :ping_pong:")
    .setDescription(`Bot latency: \`${bot}ms\`\n API latency: \`${client.ws.ping}ms\``)
    .setColor("#31e8b7")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`);
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [ping] });
},
};
```

I am using discord.js v13, please tell me how do I fix this error,
Thank you.

Comment: Did you define `client`?

Comment: yes @Jim, I did

Comment: pls help someone

Answer (score 2):

Swap your (message, client) with (client, message)

```js
execute(client, message) {
    const bot = message.createdTimestamp - Date.now();
    const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Pong! :ping_pong:")
    .setDescription(`Bot latency: \`${bot}ms\`\n API latency: \`${client.ws.ping}ms\``)
    .setColor("#31e8b7")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`);
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [ping] });
},
};
```

Comment: hey, thanks but it is still showing the same error

Comment: arburich can u please help?